# Unmerge and paste cells down with vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am facing the problem to proecess a report I got into a useful structured excel model.

My problem is that cells in this report are merged and now I would like to unmerge them to process the information much easier.

I tried to record something using the macro recorder, but I am unsure how to automate it on every cell in the sheet.

I would like to let the output look like that:

[image]

This is the part I recorded:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A2:A3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A3")
    Range("A2:A3").Select
End Sub
```

Any suggestions how to rewrite this macro to do the merging and pasting automatically?

Appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I tried to use the selection, however, I am currently facing the problem of not knowing how to get next cell:

```
Sub split()
'
'Dim C As Double
'Dim R As Double
Dim Rng As Range

'select cells
Set Rng = Selection

'C = Rng
'R = 10
For Each cell In Rng
'starts in row 2 and A -> cell 2,1 is the first cell or A2
cell.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    'Cells(R + 1, C) = Cells(R, C)
    If cell.Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Finished splitting and copying!"): End
 '   If C = 7 Then C = 0: R = R + 2
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Check if `selection.mergecells= true` then create a new row using datas from the top row

Comment: @Hearner I am really a vba newbie. Would you be so kind to provide some example code. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Ok I'm trying a code, if it works i'll give it yo you :)

Comment: I gave it to you. Did it help ? If not, tell me, i'll give you another

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine with me

Comment: @Hearner Thx for your answer! I am currently trying to change the method using only a selected range. Any suggestion how to change your method?

Comment: @Hearner I am getting an error here: `Range("K:S").MergeCells = False ' remove merge` my error is `unable to set the MergeCells property of the Range class`

Comment: Try adding your `Sheets` before like `Sheets("Sheet1").range("K:S")` or `Range(cells(2, 11), cells(2+NbRows, 11+ NbCols))`

Comment: I don't think `Set Rng = Selection` works, because you have to get a selection. `Rng` is nothing in your code, you actually have to give it a range. In your example it's `Range("A2:I11")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Sub Macro1()

    NbRows = Sheets("Feuil1").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    NbCols = 9 ' If it doesn't change

   Range("A2:I11").Copy Destination:= _
        Range("K2")
   Range("K:S").MergeCells = False ' remove merge

    For i = 2 To NbRows ' Number of rows
        For j = 11 To NbCols + NbCols ' Number of cols
            If Cells(i, j) = "" Then
                Cells(i, j) = Cells(i - 1, j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

My code copy-paste the datas from the first table to the cell "K2" (as in your example). Then, you remove the merge that will left some blanks. What you want to do is if cells(i , 1) is empty, then you just use the data from above (cells(i-1, 1))

Answer (score 1):

if the data you want to change is on columns a to g and your are starting from row 2 and assuming all of the cell are not empty

try this code:

```
Sub split()
'
Dim C As Double
Dim R As Double

C = 1
R = 2
For C = 1 To 7

Cells(R, C).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    Cells(R + 1, C) = Cells(R, C)
    If Cells(R, C).Value = "" Then MsgBox ("PROJECT ENDED"): End
    If C = 7 Then C = 0: R = R + 2
    Next C

    End Sub
```

Please save your data before running the macro. You cannot undo.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Can this also be done only using the user`s selection? Please also see my update!